# I need to make a large directory with several sub-directories portable

Tags: shell, compression, data-storage, archiving

I have a dataset contained in a directory that has about 30,000 sub-directories.  Each of these directories contains a text file and another sub-directory.  This sub-directory contains some number of text files (ranging from 0 text files, to hundreds).  Many of my colleagues use this dataset, but as it is it takes at least 6 hours to transfer the dataset from one of the computers/hard disks in the lab to another - not because of the size of the dataset, but because of the cumbersome format in which it is stored.  I would like to create some archive (such as .tar.gz) to store these data such that they can be quickly transfered between computers.  I wanted to see if anyone has worked with something like this before and can tell me the fastest, best way to do it?  I am thinking that a shell-script might be quicker than just creating the archive myself.

Comment: Running Linux? You might have more luck at superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:  NFS mount the directory.  Then a windows box or a unix box can access the directory.

Comment:  directory structures like that are bad news on inodes in a filesystem, and increase search times as well.

Answer: This will work on any POSIX compliant unix box, and assumes there is just one base directory for your repository--

```
cd /path/to/archive; tar cvf mycharhive.tar ./archive_dir;  gzip myarchive.tar
```

This creates a relative path tar archive - meaning you can unpack it to a low-level directory, instead of off the root.